# How do I fold directories in Gerrit project view?

Tags: gerrit

In Gerrit Code Review you can view a list of all projects in `Projects > List`.

The projects are listed as one long list that is organised alphabetically. If you have a large number of projects, it quickly becomes cluttered and it is difficult to navigate.

I can organise my projects in subdirectories, which Gerrit shows as such. This already helps to add structure. See image below.

[image: Gerrit subdirectories]

Is it possible to 'fold' these directories? For instance, fold directory `playground`, so that you only see the directory and not the projects in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can only use the search and type `playground/` as filter.